# Can I make a Google Voice phone call using Google Talk?

Tags: google-voice, google-talk

I have this dialog in GV with an option to use Google Talk. But nothing happens in GT. Is this a problem, or is it not possible to make a call with GT?

[image: GV]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try opening Gmail in a tab along with Google Voice. Also, make sure you have [the plugin](http://www.google.com/chat/video) installed.

Comment: This works, I get a dialog in the Gmail tab showing a call being initiated. I can also just make a call from Gmail, there's no need for the Google Voice tab. Unfortunately, there's no sound for me though =(

Comment: If the audio is not working, go to GMail Chat settings and check that microphone and speakers are set to the correct device, and click on Verify your settings.  If you do not have a current version of the Google Talk browser plugins installed, update to the latest version: http://www.google.com/talk/